# SimpleXMLElement output format

Tags: php, xml

I'm using SimpleXMLElement for create datafeed page: Here the code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<Products />");

foreach ($products as $pro) {
    $track = $xml -> addChild('Product');
    $track -> addChild('simple_sku', "<![CDATA[ ABC ]]>");
}
Header('Content-type: text/xml');
print($xml -> asXML());
```

and the output:

```
<Products>
    <Product>
        <simple_sku><![CDATA[ ABC ]]></simple_sku>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

I want to know how to turn output into format like this:

```
<Products>
    <Product>
        <simple_sku>
            <![CDATA[ ABC ]]>
        </simple_sku>
    </Product>
<Products>
```

Thanks you a lot.

Comment: Please add language tag

Comment: Why you can not use the first format?

Comment: I'm confused too. My client ask me to make a xml datafeed to another partner to add product data to they database. I created that but the partner say this code is not well form so they bot can't read it.

Comment: The first XML is fine. If they cannot read it, they should fix their parser. Or stop calling it XML and say "We need it in this XML-lookalike proprietary format".

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with **SimpleXML** so I advice you to use **DOMDocument**.

Usage example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($simpleXml->asXML());
```

Comment: So generate a document with the first (SimpleXML). Output it to an XML string, read that string back (in DOMDocument) and parse it, and output it again. Only a couple of lines but a lot of overhead. Isn't there a simpler solution? Maybe it's better to not use SimpleXML at all, and generate the document using DOMDocument in the first place.

Comment: It's not possible with SimpleXML so switching to DOMDocument looks like not a bad idea..